# Importing .csv files to SSIS

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, csv, ssis

For reasons best known to a supplier I am being provided a number of `.CSV` files in both ANSI and UTF formats and this is confusing my flat file load process. Basically, I cannot rely on the format being the same each time, although the structure is consistent.

So my questions are:

1. Does the fact that my flat file process has issues with (UTF and ANSI) mean that I have not set up the flat file connection properly?
2. I believe I have identified two possible solutions, but which of these solutions would be best?

   1. A split by type (ANSI vs UTF) and if so how?
   2. Convert all the `.csv` files to "excel" as part of a VB/C# script task? For "excel" read any other common format.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flat file connection manager **change code page** to 65001 (utf -8)

sample com [image]